# Katalon Studio: Retry Url Until Successful

Tags: katalon-studio

I am using Katalon studio with the Navigate to Url action.

It would be useful to me to be able to retry this action until there is no error loading the page, either the 'connection refused' or 404 type error.

After the web page loads succesfully, it is OK to go ahead and execute the rest of my script.

Is there any example of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, just change the css selector:

```
TestObject errorMessage = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'span.error-message-example')

while (!WebUI.verifyElementVisible(errorMessage, 3, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
      WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://example.com')
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, execution of verifyElementVisible(...) seems to block if the element is not present on the page (which might be the browser error page).  I am seeing if verifyElementPresent(...) has similar behavior.

Comment: Add failure handling, like this: `WebUI.verifyElementVisible(errorMessage, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)`. That way, the test will continue if the element is not present.

Comment: The function has a third parameter for timeout in seconds, so this worked: `while (!WebUI.verifyElementPresent(testObject, 2, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){`  Is there any place to see more documentation on this?

Comment: Check out the official [docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-verify-element-visible.html). And accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the help however while I did upvote, I specifically did not accept the answer because the first example does not meet the criteria I specified.  The comment following-up on that appears to have a syntax error.(wrong method signature) which I had to identify on my own.  I would accept the answer if I saw it was edited to 1) match the question I asked and 2) had no syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue, I found that I kept having 404 or connection reset issue if CPU is over-utilized. However I need to run a number of test cases so it is normal my CPU is overloaded.

I writen the following **Chrome** retry logic and use this for a year or so, been serving me well for :

```
for (times in 1..5 ) {
    try {
        WebUI.openBrowser('')
        WebUI.navigateToUrl(url)
        //Chrome
        WebUI.verifyTextNotPresent("ERR_CONNECTION_RESET", false)
        break
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        println "Cannot navigate to URL, try again in " + times
        WebUI.closeBrowser()
        WebUI.delay(1)
        if(times >= 5){
            //False error
            WebUI.verifyMatch('1', '0', false)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if anything failed during initial startup it will try again for 5 time before give up.

See if this is something that helps you as well.